# Vue JS with vue-router not loading vueified components

Tags: browserify, vue.js, laravel-elixir, vue-router

I am developing a web application which makes use of vue-router for an SPA with a Laravel 5 backend. It makes use of `.vue` files for app components which are run through `laravel-elixir-vueify` in order to create the required JavaScript.

I have set up vue-router along with Vue successfully and can load components defined in the same file as the main Vue and Vue router instances.

The problem comes however when I try and require a component which is contained within a `.vue` file. Despite browserify / vueify reporting a successful run when I inspect the Vue instance there are only anonymous component fragments shown within the instance by Vue dev-tools, and no markup placed within the `router-view`.

[image: Vue Devtools]

There are no errors within the console, although it looks as though the external components are not being loaded correctly.

Examples of the various code and files are as follows:

**gulpfile.js**

```
...
    mix.browserify('dashboard.js');
...
```

**dashboardOverview.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Overview</h1>
        <img src="//placehold.it/320x100" style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 15px" alt="Pathway Visualisation" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {}

</script>
```

Where `dashboardOverview.vue` is located at `resources\assets\js\components\dashboardOverview.vue`.

**Main View**

```
@section('content')
<div id="app">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <a v-link="{ path: '/activate' }">Activate</a>|
    <a v-link="{ path: '/' }">Overview</a>
    <router-view></router-view>
</div>
@endsection
```

This is supplemented by the following JavaScript:

```
var Vue = require('vue');
var VueRouter = require('vue-router');

Vue.use(VueRouter)

/* Components */
var dashboardOverview = require('./components/dashboardOverview.vue');
var userSetup = require('./components/userSetup.vue');

var App = Vue.extend();

var router = new VueRouter()
Vue.config.debug = true

router.map({
    '*': {
        component: Vue.extend({template: '<h4>404 Not found</h4>'})
    },
    '/': {
        component: dashboardOverview
    },
    '/activate': {
        component: userSetup
    }
})

router.start(App, '#app')
```

Where `dashboard.js` is located at `resources\assets\js\dashboard.js`.

Comment: Thinking about answers, but for starters fragment instances cause a bunch of weird issues.  You should wrap the component in a div always

Comment: Hi @Jeff, thanks for the suggestion. I have wrapped the component in a `div` although the problem still persists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I set up a minimal test project and managed to successfully achieve what I was aiming for.

The end result of this was some Node packages which had incompatible versions, and also packages that weren't required.

I pruned my `packages.json` file and then reinstalled the required `vue`, `vue-router`, and `laravel-elixir-vueify` packages to ensure everything was installed correctly with the correct dependencies and it has worked since.